# Fast display Bitmaps in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, canvas, bitmap

I wrote a little client-server application, that transfers Bitmaps over tcp. The server part works like a charm, but on the client side I'm not sure how to display the received bitmaps. The client backend calls everytime a new picture is received a method in the activity, that should update and display the bitmap...up to 25 fps.
What is the nicest solution?

I wrote an own view, but calling `setContentView`
doesn't work for me, it missed displaying the bitmaps and the screen stays black, until the server closes, then one image is displayed correctly. I even tried something like this:

```
this.image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

and

```
    public void setImage(BufferedImage bufImage) {
    if (bufImage.hasBitmap()) {
        this.image.setImageBitmap(bufImage.getBitmap());
    }
}
```

(I wrote an own BufferedImage class, that holds correct Bitmaps)

Even with image.invalidate() nothing happens until the server closes the connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you're doing your network IO on the user interface thread. What happens in that case is that nothing in the UI get updated till the network operations are complete. If so what you need to do is create a thread to run the server IO, and have it call back to the UI thread with frames to display. Here's some general info about how threading and the user interface interact that should help if so:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i had this idea nearly the second after posting this question. Now the "backend" is an own thread and calls the ui with the new Bitmaps, but I have the same problem mentioned above: The one and only picture displayed is displayed the second I close the server..

Comment: Can you post the code for the updated version? Maybe there's something else keeping the bitmaps from being rendered.

Comment: Ok now I gave a try to the AsyncTask class: public class Backend extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{.... protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { load pictures, call ui to display}} and in the ui: public void setImage(BufferedImage bufImage) {if (bufImage.hasBitmap()) {this.image.setImageBitmap(bufImage.getBitmap());}}

Comment: You're just updating the image view from the background now without synchronizing to the UI thread. And you're misusing AsyncTask, which is meant for single update tasks. What you need to do is post() a runnable to the view you want to update as described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks for the help. The solution is to post runnables to the ImageView in the content :)